# Express Static variable folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have two folders, each folder contains a different theme for each store.

/angularApp_v1

/angularApp_v2

I have a middleware to find out which folder should be served when a request enters. Example:

-- www.storev1.com should go to /angularApp_v1

-- www.storev2.com should go to /angularApp_v2

Whats the best way to route each domain to their correct express.static folder.?

EDIT:

```
var storeMiddlware = function(req, res, next) {
    getStoreTheme(req.hostname, function(response){
        req.storeTheme = response.theme;
    }
})

app.use(storeMiddleware);
app.use('/', express.static(req.storeTheme));
```

where req.storeTheme = the folder (angularApp_v1 or angularApp_v2)

SOLVED: using '[serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static)'

```
var themeAssests = {
    'v1': serveStatic('angularApp_v1'),
    'v2': serveStatic('angularApp_v2')
}

app.use("/", function(req, res, next) {
    themeAssests[req.storeTheme](req, res, next);
})
```

Comment: Also u have two different hostname, one is storev1 and other is storev2, so they will be running on different ports right, which means different node servers

Comment: Then there is no need to specify two different folder, unless there were two different folders for one application.

Comment: @zenwraight each folder is a theme, and the store can choose which theme. So they need to be hosted on the same node server. Theres a variable on the database that decides which folder should be served for an individual store

Comment: The folder can change dynamically so theres a middleware to check DB and get what theme the store is using.

Comment: @zenwraight I updated my question to include the middleWare, and an example of what I want to acomplish. express.static(req.storeTheme) is not possible because req.storeTheme isnt defined until the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this problem, view my question I included the solution over there.